# Selecting from xml file into a dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file as shown below. In it i want to select the values in the nodes and insert them into their separate dictionary. I have my code below. When i iterate through, the dictionary count returns zero. Suggestions please.

```
 <EmployeeFinance>
    <EstateId>157</EstateId>
    <EmpPersonal_Id>494</EmpPersonal_Id>
    <NonStatDedct>
      <DeductedAmt NonStatID="106">5000</DeductedAmt>
      <DeductedAmt DeductionID="106">5000</DeductedAmt>
    </NonStatDedct>
 </EmployeeFinance>
```

.

```
 var query = from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
 where (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id") == empID
 select new NonStatDed_Breakdown
 {
     Nonst = nm.Element("NonStatDedct").Elements("DeductedAmt").Where(a => a.Attributes().Equals("NonStatID")).ToDictionary(a => (int)a.Attribute("NonStatID"), a => (double)a),
     Deduc = nm.Element("NonStatDedct").Elements("DeductedAmt").Where(a => a.Attributes().Equals("DeductionID")).ToDictionary(a => (int)a.Attribute("DeductionID"), a => (double)a)
 };
 var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

When i check `resultquery.Nonst` and `resultquery.Deduc`, the count returns 0. I do not know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
a.Attributes().Equals("NonStatID")
```

You need to get your attribute value and compare it with a real value not the name of the attribute:

```
.Where(a => (int)a.Attribute("NonStatID") ==  statId)
```

Or if you are looking for attribute name then you can use `Any` method with `Where` like this:

```
.First(a => a.Attributes().Any(x => x.Name == "NonStatID"))
```

So then your code should look like this:

```
 var query = from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
     where (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id") == empID
     select new NonStatDed_Breakdown
     {
         Nonst = nm.Element("NonStatDedct")
                  .Elements("DeductedAmt")
                  .Where(a => a.Attributes().Any(x => x.Name == "NonStatID"))                   
                  .ToDictionary(a => (int)a.Attribute("NonStatID"), a => (double)a),

         Deduc = nm.Element("NonStatDedct") 
                 .Elements("DeductedAmt")
                 .Where(a => a.Attributes().Any(x => x.Name == "DeductionID"))       
                 .ToDictionary(a => (int)a.Attribute("DeductionID"), a => (double)a)
    };
```

Comment: I dont have a real value such a StatId. Thats why i was trying to query where the attribute name is "NonStatID". Can i do that?

Comment: On the part - .ToDictionary(a => (int)a.Attribute("NonStatID"), a => (double)a) .. i am getting an error saying .ToDictionary definition is not there..

Comment: @Maverick1415 right it's my mistake.Change first to Where